# Parse: can't assign relationship with subclasses

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Here it is: I have defined subclass of `PFUser` named `User`

```
 class User: PFUser {

    @NSManaged var name: String?
    @NSManaged var qrCode: QRCode?
}
```

and a subclass of `PFObject` named `QRCode`:

```
class HQRCode: PFObject {

    @NSManaged var code: String

    convenience init(_ code: String) {

        self.init()
        setObject(code, forKey: "code")
    }
}
```

and I have registered subclassed in `AppDelegate`:

```
QRCode.registerSubclass()
User.registerSubclass()
```

when I retrieve a QRcode from the server and assign it to the user, but unfortunately  I got the following error:

```
// retrieve and assign qrcode
newUser.qrCode = QRcode
```

> Error Domain=Parse Code=111 "schema mismatch for _User.qrCode; expected Relation but got Pointer"

What does it mean? and How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error was issuing the qrCode column in `User` class on the "Dashboard" is of type `Relationship`. to fix it I set that to type `Pointer`